# Remove href from inner div tag?

Tags: jquery, tags, click, href

I use one jquery for showing tips.
It creates DIV tag inside A tag. For example...

```
<a href="mypage.html">Title</a>
```

On hover becomes..

```
<a href="mypage.html">Title <div class="tooltip">My text....</div></a>
```

Its working great. But the "My text...." is clickable link (because its inside the A>HREF). 
Is there any way to make it not clickable without moving it out from the A tag?

Comment: Yes - dont create the div inside the anchor .... post your code for creating the divs and it might help !

Comment: If you don't want the DIV to be clickable, then move it outside the A tag.  It's that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach an handler to your  and then check the target that generated the event, if it is the div, just return false

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   if($(e.target).hasClass('tooltip')){
      return false;
   }
});
```

fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/FfVWv/

Comment: That will not keep the element from being clickable (and appear clickable), it will only prevent the default action when you click on the element.

Comment: But, this is just a dumb way to solve the problem.  If you don't want it clickable, remove it from the A tag.  This solution is like when your house is too cold because the air conditioning it turned down too low and someone suggests that you light a fire in the fireplace to heat up the house.  No, turn the thermostat to the desired temperature - don't apply an ineficient bandaid to the problem that doesn't really fix the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

You should not put a div tag inside an anchor tag anyway, as that blows up in browsers that doesn't support HTML 5.

Comment: Even if you set the A to block?

Comment: Yes you can, just check if  the target of the events has the class tooltip and then return false

Comment: @Jleagle: Adding style to the HTML doesn't turn invalid HTML into valid HTML. The browser parses the HTML before the CSS is loaded, so CSS can't affect the parsing.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: No, you can't. That will *not* keep the element from being clickable (and appear clickable), it will only prevent the default action when you click on it.

Comment: Oh, by "blows up", I thought you meant renderers horribly. Not creates invalid mark up.

Comment: @Jleagle: The result of the invalid markup is that it blows up. The usual way that browsers handle this is to either move the div tag outside the anchor, or end the anchor where the div starts.

Comment: @Guffa in that sense you are right, but you could style the element so that it looks like a "normal div"